# Google cloud messaging GCM - Push Notification not being sent (Server Side)

Tags: php, android, google-cloud-messaging

I am able to get the device id and save it to my database, and when something happens, I try to send the push notification but it does not get delivered to the phone.  Here is what I do in my PHP:

```
$url = 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send';

$device_ids = array( $device_id );

$headers = array('Authorization: key=' . 'my_api_key',
'Content-Type: application/json');

$t_data = array();
$t_data['message'] = 'Someone commented on your business.';

$t_json = array( 'registration_ids' => $device_ids , 'data' => $t_data );

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array( 'Authorization: key=my_id', 'Content-Type: application/json' ) );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $t_json ) );

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
if ($result === FALSE)
{
     die('Curl failed: ' . curl_error($ch));
}

curl_close($ch);
```

and here is the result I get from the curl_exec call:

```
{"multicast_id":8714083978034301091,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"r‌​esults":[{"message_id":"0:1350807053347963%9aab4bd8f9fd7ecd"}]}
```

One thing I am wondering is whether I have to do something extra in the app like write my own Reciever class?
Thanks!

EDIT:

Here is my GCMIntentService class:

```
package com.problemio;

import static com.google.android.gcm.GCMConstants.ERROR_SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE;
import static com.google.android.gcm.GCMConstants.EXTRA_ERROR;
import static com.google.android.gcm.GCMConstants.EXTRA_REGISTRATION_ID;
import static com.google.android.gcm.GCMConstants.EXTRA_SPECIAL_MESSAGE;
import static com.google.android.gcm.GCMConstants.EXTRA_TOTAL_DELETED;
import static com.google.android.gcm.GCMConstants.EXTRA_UNREGISTERED;
import static com.google.android.gcm.GCMConstants.INTENT_FROM_GCM_LIBRARY_RETRY;
import static com.google.android.gcm.GCMConstants.INTENT_FROM_GCM_MESSAGE;
import static com.google.android.gcm.GCMConstants.INTENT_FROM_GCM_REGISTRATION_CALLBACK;
import static com.google.android.gcm.GCMConstants.VALUE_DELETED_MESSAGES;

import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import com.google.android.gcm.GCMBaseIntentService;

import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.IntentService;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.PowerManager;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import utils.GCMConstants;

public class GCMIntentService extends GCMBaseIntentService 
{
    public GCMIntentService() 
    {
            super(ProblemioActivity.SENDER_ID);
    }

    @Override
      protected void onRegistered(Context ctxt, String regId) {
        Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "onRegistered: " + regId);
        Toast.makeText(this, regId, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      }

      @Override
      protected void onUnregistered(Context ctxt, String regId) {
        Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "onUnregistered: " + regId);
      }

      @Override
      protected void onMessage(Context ctxt, Intent message) {
        Bundle extras=message.getExtras();

        for (String key : extras.keySet()) {
          Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(),
                String.format("onMessage: %s=%s", key,
                              extras.getString(key)));
        }
      }

      @Override
      protected void onError(Context ctxt, String errorMsg) {
        Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "onError: " + errorMsg);
      }

      @Override
      protected boolean onRecoverableError(Context ctxt, String errorMsg) {
        Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "onRecoverableError: " + errorMsg);

        return(true);
      } 
}
```

UPDATE:

Looking at LogCat, it turned out that the message is getting to the device. But the device is not displaying the push notification for some reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the response it seems that the message is delivered. On Android you should have a GCMIntentService class that extends GCMBaseIntentService, to receive the message on the device. You should check the gcm-demo-client that comes in the SDK samples for a good approach on how to implement this on the app. There you only need set the SENDER_ID (your google proyect number) in the CommonUtilities class to receive messages from your server.

More info [here](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/google/gcm/demo.html).

To generate the notification on the GCMIntentService you can use:

```
 //Issues a notification to inform the user that server has sent a message.

private static void generateNotification(Context context, String message, String title,) {

        int icon = R.drawable.logo;

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, AnActivity.class);

        // set intent so it does not start a new activity
        notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);        
        Uri defaultSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);            

         Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
         .setContentTitle(title)
         .setContentText(message)
         .setContentIntent(intent)
         .setSmallIcon(icon)
         .setLights(Color.YELLOW, 1, 2)
         .setAutoCancel(true)
         .setSound(defaultSound)
         .build();

        notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
}
```

Have you also registered the receiver on the manifest? Under the application tag?

```
    <!--
      BroadcastReceiver that will receive intents from GCM
      services and handle them to the custom IntentService.

      The com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND permission is necessary
      so only GCM services can send data messages for the app.
    -->
    <receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <!-- Receives the actual messages. -->
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <!-- Receives the registration id. -->
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
            <category android:name="com.google.android.gcm.demo.app" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <!--
      Application-specific subclass of GCMBaseIntentService that will
      handle received messages.

      By default, it must be named .GCMIntentService, unless the
      application uses a custom BroadcastReceiver that redefines its name.
    -->
    <service android:name=".GCMIntentService" />
```

Comment: I just posted my GCMIntentService but I am not sure how to adjust it to create the push notification.

Comment: You can't see this on the logs? 

 Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(),
                String.format("onMessage: %s=%s", key,
                              extras.getString(key)));

Comment: so is the problem that I just don't have the generateNotification() method in my GCMIntentService?

Comment: if you are seeing the logs, but not the notification, then you need that method to create one.

Comment: actually I am testing on a device, so I am not sure how to check the logs from the device :)

Comment: you can see the logs on the Logcat in eclipse, the same as the ADV. Only put the device in debug mode and keep it connected with the USB cable.

Comment: sounds good - let me try to add your method to my service, and I will post back with results. Thank you!

Comment: by the way, what is the NotificationCompat class? It isn't a standard library class it seems.

Comment: Which android version is your target? That class is on the android support library and i think it runs all the way down API 8. I can give you a workaround, but uses deprecated methods to create the notification...

Comment: hmm..I am on version 16 I think. Just updated. And my min target api is 4. Maybe I just need an extra jar file for the support library?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18424/discussion-between-nsemeniuk-and-genadinik)

Comment: will u help me on t his http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18571844/gcm-not-sending-the-notifications/18572611?noredirect=1#comment27328335_18572611

Answer (score 1):

You only need a collapseKey if you are planning to have your messages overwrite the previous message of that type. So if you are sending a message that the app needs to sync you can give it a collapse key so it will only send 1 sync message. The official [docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/gcm.html#send-msg) describe how to use it.

Comment: yeah but would you know why the push isn't being created?

Comment: do you know for sure that it isn't getting created? or is it just not showing up on the device - which could be caused by several different issues

Comment: actually I only know for sure it isn't getting to the device.  How do I tell if it is being generated but not showing up on the device?

Comment: you should be getting a response of some kind. it will tell you if you have a problem with the request, or if they can't find the registration id, etc. what response are you getting?

Comment: here is the result from the server: {"multicast_id":8714083978034301091,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1350807053347963%9aab4bd8f9fd7ecd"}]}

Comment: that means that the message was create and sent successfully and your device should be receiving it. i would stick some breakpoints in your GCMIntentService (specifically in onMessageReceived) and see what you are receiving from the server.

Answer (score 0):

While sending notification from GCM Server, which url to be used?
https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send or 
https://gcm-http.googleapis.com/gcm/send