# GCM Not Sending the Notifications

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-messaging

I have created a application that uses the GCM functionality. When I am posting the message from the server to the device in response i am getting the message id. After sending the message from the server when I am again running the application then I am getting the response on the device. It is not coming as a notification like GMAIL notification once app is installed when the server sends message it will show notification. I am posting my complete server and client code.Please help me to resolve the issue.

**Issue I got:** When I am running again my android application then what I have send from the server side on the that time it is showing the message but I want it to be as a notification what I am sending from the server ...

**Server-side Code**

```
/**
 * Servlet implementation class GCMBroadcast
 */
@WebServlet("/GCMBroadcast")
public class GCMBroadcast extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


    private static final String SENDER_ID = "";


    private static final String ANDROID_DEVICE = "";


    private List<String> androidTargets = new ArrayList<String>();


    public GCMBroadcast() {

        super();


        androidTargets.add(ANDROID_DEVICE);

    }


    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {


        String collapseKey = "";
        String userMessage = "";

        try {
            userMessage = request.getParameter("Message");
            collapseKey = request.getParameter("CollapseKey");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }


        Sender sender = new Sender(SENDER_ID);


        Message message = new Message.Builder()


        .collapseKey(collapseKey)
        .timeToLive(30)
        .delayWhileIdle(true)
        .addData("message", userMessage)
        .build();

        try {

            MulticastResult result = sender.send(message, androidTargets, 1);
            System.out.println("Response: " + result.getResults().toString());
            if (result.getResults() != null) {

                int canonicalRegId = result.getCanonicalIds();
                if (canonicalRegId != 0) {
                    System.out.println("response " +canonicalRegId );
                }
            } else {
                int error = result.getFailure();
                System.out.println("Broadcast failure: " + error);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        request.setAttribute("CollapseKey", collapseKey);
        request.setAttribute("Message", userMessage);

        request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp").forward(request, response);

    }

}
```

DemoActivity Code

```
public class DemoActivity extends Activity {

    public static final String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "message";
    public static final String PROPERTY_REG_ID = "registration_id";
    private static final String PROPERTY_APP_VERSION = "appVersion";
    private static final int PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 9000;

    /**
     * Substitute you own sender ID here. This is the project number you got
     * from the API Console, as described in "Getting Started."
     */
    String SENDER_ID = "";

    /**
     * Tag used on log messages.
     */
    static final String TAG = "GCM Demo";

    TextView mDisplay;
    GoogleCloudMessaging gcm;
    AtomicInteger msgId = new AtomicInteger();
    Context context;

    String regid;

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mDisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.display);

        context = getApplicationContext();

        // Check device for Play Services APK. If check succeeds, proceed with GCM registration.
        if (checkPlayServices()) {
            gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);
            regid = getRegistrationId(context);
            Log.d("Registration id ", regid+"");

            if (regid.isEmpty()) {
                registerInBackground();
            }
        } else {
            Log.i(TAG, "No valid Google Play Services APK found.");
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        // Check device for Play Services APK.
        checkPlayServices();
    }

    /**
     * Check the device to make sure it has the Google Play Services APK. If
     * it doesn't, display a dialog that allows users to download the APK from
     * the Google Play Store or enable it in the device's system settings.
     */
    private boolean checkPlayServices() {
        int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
        if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
            if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(resultCode)) {
                GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resultCode, this,
                        PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST).show();
            } else {
                Log.i(TAG, "This device is not supported.");
                finish();
            }
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Stores the registration ID and the app versionCode in the application's
     * {@code SharedPreferences}.
     *
     * @param context application's context.
     * @param regId registration ID
     */
    private void storeRegistrationId(Context context, String regId) {
        final SharedPreferences prefs = getGcmPreferences(context);
        int appVersion = getAppVersion(context);
        Log.i(TAG, "Saving regId on app version " + appVersion);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putString(PROPERTY_REG_ID, regId);
        editor.putInt(PROPERTY_APP_VERSION, appVersion);
        editor.commit();
    }

    /**
     * Gets the current registration ID for application on GCM service, if there is one.
     * <p>
     * If result is empty, the app needs to register.
     *
     * @return registration ID, or empty string if there is no existing
     *         registration ID.
     */
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    private String getRegistrationId(Context context) {
        final SharedPreferences prefs = getGcmPreferences(context);
        String registrationId = prefs.getString(PROPERTY_REG_ID, "");
        if (registrationId.isEmpty()) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Registration not found.");
            return "";
        }
        // Check if app was updated; if so, it must clear the registration ID
        // since the existing regID is not guaranteed to work with the new
        // app version.
        int registeredVersion = prefs.getInt(PROPERTY_APP_VERSION, Integer.MIN_VALUE);
        int currentVersion = getAppVersion(context);
        if (registeredVersion != currentVersion) {
            Log.i(TAG, "App version changed.");
            return "";
        }
        return registrationId;
    }

    /**
     * Registers the application with GCM servers asynchronously.
     * <p>
     * Stores the registration ID and the app versionCode in the application's
     * shared preferences.
     */
    private void registerInBackground() {
        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
                String msg = "";
                try {
                    if (gcm == null) {
                        gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(context);
                    }
                    regid = gcm.register(SENDER_ID);
                    Log.d("registration Id", regid+"");
                    msg = "Device registered, registration ID=" + regid;

                    // You should send the registration ID to your server over HTTP, so it
                    // can use GCM/HTTP or CCS to send messages to your app.
                    sendRegistrationIdToBackend();

                    // For this demo: we don't need to send it because the device will send
                    // upstream messages to a server that echo back the message using the
                    // 'from' address in the message.

                    // Persist the regID - no need to register again.
                    storeRegistrationId(context, regid);
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    msg = "Error :" + ex.getMessage();
                    // If there is an error, don't just keep trying to register.
                    // Require the user to click a button again, or perform
                    // exponential back-off.
                }
                return msg;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String msg) {
                mDisplay.append(msg + "\n");
            }
        }.execute(null, null, null);
    }

    // Send an upstream message.
    public void onClick(final View view) {

        if (view == findViewById(R.id.send)) {
            new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {
                @Override
                protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
                    String msg = "";
                    try {
                        Bundle data = new Bundle();
                        data.putString("my_message", "Hello World");
                        data.putString("my_action", "com.google.android.gcm.demo.app.ECHO_NOW");
                        String id = Integer.toString(msgId.incrementAndGet());
                        gcm.send(SENDER_ID + "@gcm.googleapis.com", id, data);
                        msg = "Sent message";
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        msg = "Error :" + ex.getMessage();
                    }
                    return msg;
                }

                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(String msg) {
                    mDisplay.append(msg + "\n");
                }
            }.execute(null, null, null);
        } else if (view == findViewById(R.id.clear)) {
            mDisplay.setText("");
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    /**
     * @return Application's version code from the {@code PackageManager}.
     */
    private static int getAppVersion(Context context) {
        try {
            PackageInfo packageInfo = context.getPackageManager()
                    .getPackageInfo(context.getPackageName(), 0);
            return packageInfo.versionCode;
        } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
            // should never happen
            throw new RuntimeException("Could not get package name: " + e);
        }
    }

    /**
     * @return Application's {@code SharedPreferences}.
     */
    private SharedPreferences getGcmPreferences(Context context) {
        // This sample app persists the registration ID in shared preferences, but
        // how you store the regID in your app is up to you.
        return getSharedPreferences(DemoActivity.class.getSimpleName(),
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    }
    /**
     * Sends the registration ID to your server over HTTP, so it can use GCM/HTTP or CCS to send
     * messages to your app. Not needed for this demo since the device sends upstream messages
     * to a server that echoes back the message using the 'from' address in the message.
     */
    private void sendRegistrationIdToBackend() {
      // Your implementation here.
    }
}
```

**GCMBroadCastReciver**

```
public class GcmBroadcastReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // Explicitly specify that GcmIntentService will handle the intent.
        ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),
                GcmIntentService.class.getName());
        // Start the service, keeping the device awake while it is launching.
        startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));
        setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);
    }
}
```

**GCMIntentServicve**

```
public class GcmIntentService extends IntentService {
    public static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
    private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder;

    public GcmIntentService() {
        super("GcmIntentService");
    }
    public static final String TAG = "GCM Demo";

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);
        // The getMessageType() intent parameter must be the intent you received
        // in your BroadcastReceiver.
        String messageType = gcm.getMessageType(intent);

        if (!extras.isEmpty()) {  // has effect of unparcelling Bundle
            /*
             * Filter messages based on message type. Since it is likely that GCM will be
             * extended in the future with new message types, just ignore any message types you're
             * not interested in, or that you don't recognize.
             */
            if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_SEND_ERROR.equals(messageType)) {
                sendNotification("Send error: " + extras.toString());
            } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_DELETED.equals(messageType)) {
                sendNotification("Deleted messages on server: " + extras.toString());
            // If it's a regular GCM message, do some work.
            } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_MESSAGE.equals(messageType)) {
                // This loop represents the service doing some work.
                for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Working... " + (i + 1)
                            + "/5 @ " + SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(5000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    }
                }
                Log.i(TAG, "Completed work @ " + SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
                // Post notification of received message.
                sendNotification("Received: " + extras.toString());
                Log.i(TAG, "Received: " + extras.toString());
            }
        }
        // Release the wake lock provided by the WakefulBroadcastReceiver.
        GcmBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
    }

    // Put the message into a notification and post it.
    // This is just one simple example of what you might choose to do with
    // a GCM message.
    private void sendNotification(String msg) {
        mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)
                this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                new Intent(this, DemoActivity.class), 0);
        Log.d("Notification Message==", msg);
        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_gcm)
        .setContentTitle("Iween Notification")
        .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
        .bigText(msg))
        .setContentText(msg);

        Uri notificationSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        mBuilder.setSound(notificationSound);

        mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
        mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

**Manifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  - Copyright 2013 Google Inc.
  -
  - Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may not
  - use this file except in compliance with the License. You may obtain a copy
  - of the License at
  -
  - http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
  -
  - Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  - distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT
  - WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. See the
  - License for the specific language governing permissions and limitations
  - under the License.
-->
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.newgcmproject" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0">

    <!-- GCM requires Android SDK version 2.2 (API level 8) or above. -->
    <!-- The targetSdkVersion is optional, but it's always a good practice
         to target higher versions. -->
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="16"/>

    <!-- GCM connects to Google Services. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <!-- GCM requires a Google account. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />

    <!-- Keeps the processor from sleeping when a message is received. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

    <!--
     Creates a custom permission so only this app can receive its messages.

     NOTE: the permission *must* be called PACKAGE.permission.C2D_MESSAGE,
           where PACKAGE is the application's package name.
    -->
    <permission android:name="com.example.newgcmproject.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.newgcmproject.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <!-- This app has permission to register and receive data message. -->
    <uses-permission
        android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

    <!-- Main activity. -->
    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".DemoActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
                android:launchMode="singleTop">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <!--
          WakefulBroadcastReceiver that will receive intents from GCM
          services and hand them to the custom IntentService.

          The com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND permission is necessary
          so only GCM services can send data messages for the app.
        -->
        <receiver
            android:name=".GcmBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <!-- Receives the actual messages. -->
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <category android:name="com.google.android.gcm.demo.app" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <service android:name=".GcmIntentService" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I am not getting any notifications on my device even if I am getting the message id when I am sending from the server side.

**Edit** 
Now I have done some changes in my code. I am getting the exception that the **service is not available**

Comment: here if u are getting message id in response than your server side code is correct.. check your brodcast receiver..

Comment: no on phone i am testing this

Comment: The problem is probably on client side. Please include your manifest, broadcast receiver and intent service (if you're using one).

Comment: Posted complete client side code also

Comment: @Gaurav, sorry friend. Can't solve your problem.. Not getting actually.

Comment: @ChintanRathod in sendNotification function that is in GCMIntentServicve i want to close it once the user selects how could i do this

Comment: @Gaurav, isn't notification close automatically when you select it?

Comment: @ChintanRathod brother can u help me on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18712300/adb-is-down-in-android/18712765

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My understanding of the parameters you are adding to the message is as follows:

The timeToLive is set to 30 seconds which is how long it will reside on the server before being deleted.

The delay_while_idle is set to true so that if the phone is locked or asleep, then the GCM server does not attempt to deliver the message.

So if you send the message and your phone is not woken up or unlocked for 30 seconds then you will never get that message.

Whilst developing your app I would delete both of these arguments, so that they default to the values of 4 weeks and false. When you have established that messages do come through, you can experiment with different values for them.

In the manifest 
I think that you receiver category is wrong. It shouldn't be

```
   <category android:name="com.avilyne.android.gcmclient" />
```

It should match the top level package name:

```
package="com.example.gcmttestproject"
```

Comment: still it is not receiving any message i have removed all these parameters

Comment: Oh well, worth a try. If your phone is connected via WiFi to the internet via a router, then it is worth toggling the phone's wifi off and on again. Many people (me included) report a delay in reception of messages. This toggling action usually 'flushes the buffer'.

Comment: when i am running my application again after sending the message from the server then it is showing me i want this message as a notification as many times i am sending the message from the server

Comment: Re the url: I'm not sure what's in your jsp (I'm doing it via PHP on my RaspberryPi) I have a URL in my php script of $url = 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send'; So I think the answer is 'Yes' - you have to post that message to the GCM server somehow

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36654/discussion-between-gaurav-and-nickt)

Comment: i have already done the changes i forgot to change in the question

Comment: the question is i want to make it as push notification that if the message is posted on the device it should be as notification for the device.What i have done is like when i am running my application then it is showing me the notification

Comment: @Gaurav, my phone is also connected with Internet via WiFi connection. When I was implementing GCM, I never faced delay in receiving messages. It immediately deliver message. On the spot.. :)

Comment: it is delivering the message when i am running the application after sending the message from the sever then after.i want to be like gmail once the message comes from the server .it shows the notification that u got the mail see i have posted the complete code i am doing some silly mistake please help me to resolve this.

Comment: @ChintanRathod waiting for your comments

Comment: @ChintanRathod brother i have updated my code on the notification click i want to open my activity and close this notification.Please check what i have wrong in this

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly you want to display the notification on the device, then open your app when you click it. To do this you can use the following code (replace MyActivity with your own on the intent):

```
//Issues a notification to inform the user that server has sent a message.

private static void generateNotification(Context context, String message, String title,) {

    int icon = R.drawable.logo;

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, MyActivity.class);

    // set intent so it does not start a new activity
    notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);        
    Uri defaultSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);            

     Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
     .setContentTitle(title)
     .setContentText(message)
     .setContentIntent(intent)
     .setSmallIcon(icon)
     .setLights(Color.YELLOW, 1, 2)
     .setAutoCancel(true)
     .setSound(defaultSound)
     .build();

    notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
```

}

This can be called on the `onMessage()` method on `GCMBaseIntentService`.

Comment: i want this as same as gmail.once it is installed whenever server sends message.at once it will show the notification my app is showing when i am again running the app after sending the message from the server