# ADB is down in Android

Tags: android, eclipse

I am getting this exception when i trying to run my application

```
[2013-09-10 12:09:21 - EffectiveNavigation] The connection to adb is down, and a severe error has occured.
[2013-09-10 12:09:21 - EffectiveNavigation] You must restart adb and Eclipse.
[2013-09-10 12:09:21 - EffectiveNavigation] Please ensure that adb is correctly located at 'E:\Configured-Eclipse\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20130522\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe' and can be executed.
```

When i tried to reset adb from eclipse it is showing this error

```
[2013-09-10 12:18:20 - adb] Attempting to restart adb, but version check failed!
```

I have tried this also from the command prompt.

```
1.adb kill-server //kill all active server
2.adb start-server //start adb server
```

**Restarted** the eclipse also but still the same error .Help me to resolve the issue.

Comment: yes just i got the solution .the problem was because of this COMODO Defense+ internet security .even thanks for u r comment Chintan

Comment: I was not on my desk.. I saw your problem right now.. just reading whole page.. great.. :)

Comment: from last three hours i was facing this problem

Comment: You are genius thats why you solved within 3 hours.. if i were at your place.. it took 6 hours.. lolz... :P

Comment: :P making a fun of my problem....@ChintanRathod ..no issue

Comment: Nope dude.. just making fun of my self.. Not your problem.. Just chill. Instead of being serious whole day, like to make one laugh for a moment :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally this was the issue

turned off **COMODO** Defense+ module and all worked....

Comment: always these AntiVirus programs do more harm than good! one of the many reasons why I switched to Linux years ago.

Answer (score 0):

If you install some application manage your phone, kill the application.

Comment: what is this i am not getting you

Answer (score 0):

First of all, make sure you can run adb.exe itself without any errors. run it in "Administrator Mode" in cmd.exe and also, "adb.exe devices" should output list of connected and recognized USB devices.

Comment: yes what u said all are working fine daemon started successfully when i start the adb .when i use adb devices it shows my device also .but when i run the application then it show me the same error

Answer (score 0):

Check update for eclipse adt first.

============== For most adb-down situations this may work. ========

1. Exit eclipse and kill the process adb.exe from Task Manager.
2. run **adb kill-server** and **adb start-server**. then retry.

If an error occurred when 'adb start-server'

Use **netstat -abn** to finger out if there is a process which is listening on **port 5037** (default adb port), and kill it. Then run 'adb start-server' or just 'adb devices'

Comment: every thing is working properly not getting any kind of error on restarting